# My re.match is taking regx as sting for imported variables from another file

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I am trying to `re.match` an imported file (ocdo_confec_param) variable (Input_File_Pattern) but it is not using [0-9] as a variable name and counting it as a string when I am printing the length.

main_scipt.py

```
import re
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from datetime import datetime
import ocdo_confec_param  as param

sharepoint_file = 'Sku Report - Biscuits (RMS) 2022  - Ocado.xlsx'

print("param.Input_File_Pattern lenght  ")
print(len(param.Input_File_Pattern))
print("sharepoint_file lenght")
print(len(sharepoint_file))

if re.match(param.Input_File_Pattern,sharepoint_file):
   print("correct file")
else :
   print("File name incorrect")
        #exit(1)
```

ocdo_confec_param.py file

```
Input_File_Pattern = r"Sku Report - Biscuits (RMS) [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]  - Ocado.xlsx"
```

Here is the output:

```
param.Input_File_Pattern lenght  
62
sharepoint_file lenght
46
File name incorrect

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't `[0-9]`, the problem is `(RMS)`. Parentheses have special meaning in regular expressions, they're used to create groups in the pattern. You need to escape them to match them literally.

You should also escape the `.` in `Ocado.xlsx`.

```
Input_File_Pattern = r"Sku Report - Biscuits \(RMS\) [0-9]{4}  - Ocado\.xlsx"
```

Comment: It worked by adding \ but I have one more doubt 
while printing Input_File_Pattern I am getting "\" as well, here is the code .

else:
        print("File name incorrect !!!  Expected file : \'" + filename + "\'")
       
i am getting / in output also eg OUTPUT :
File name incorrect !!!  Expected file : 'Sku Report - Biscuits \(RMS\) [0-9]{4}  - Ocado\.xlsx'

how can i print  it output as this:
File name incorrect !!!  Expected file : 'Sku Report - Biscuits (RMS) [0-9]{4}  - Ocado.xlsx'

Comment: There's not much you can do about that. A regular expression pattern is not really intended for display to end users.

Comment: You could use `Input_File_Pattern.replace(r'\.', '.')` to remove the backslash.